# How to add URL to InlineKeyboardButton for Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to make the button that will open URL (external hyperlink) in browser from Telegram chat. Currently, I developed only clickable action buttons.

```
update.message.reply_text(
    'Subscribe to us on Facebook and Telegram:',
    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text='on Facebook', callback_data='Facebook')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text='on Telegram', callback_data='Telegram')],
    ])
)
```

But how to make them as link (with arrow). I want to ask for users for sharing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `callback_data` argument you can use `url` and that's it.

```
update.message.reply_text(
    'Subscribe to us on Facebook and Telegram:',
    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text='on Facebook', url='https://facebook.com')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text='on Telegram', url='https://t.me')],
    ])
)
```